# Two full height columns, one divided in two stacks with same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is one column on the left-hand side and one on the right-hand side. These columns have the same height, created with flexbox:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="left flex-item">Grounds rich pumpkin spice milk aftertaste doppio cream carajillo. Espresso body iced rich caramelization brewed sit organic crema. Qui grounds doppio wings ristretto barista cream brewed coffee aftertaste ristretto that. Froth americano, french press and dark java brewed.Grounds rich pumpkin spice milk aftertaste doppio cream carajillo. Espresso body iced rich caramelization brewed sit organic crema. Qui grounds doppio wings ristretto barista cream brewed coffee aftertaste ristretto that. Froth americano, french press and dark java brewed.</div>
    <div class="right flex-item">
        <div class="stack stack-top">stack</div>
        <div class="stack stack-below">stack</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
    flex: 1 0;
}

.left, .right, .stack {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

The column on the right-hand side should be divided vertically into two stacks with the same height (50%). It should be dynamically to the height of the column on the left-hand side.

Is there a way to do it with flexbox and without using the height 
property? (No need to work in all browsers)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/regbf5qa/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make the second flex item a flexbox itself, and change the direction to column, then apply `flex: 1` to child items.

HTML (no changes)

CSS

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
    flex: 1 0;
}

.left, .right, .stack {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(2) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(2) > div {
    flex: 1;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ha0aqysk/